# Calling a plugin from a page template in TwentyEleven

Tags: php

I'm desperately trying to call a pretty simple-looking plugin (this one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-random-posts/ ) from a TwentyEleven page template. The goal being to get the thing to display not in the sidebar, but in the middle of a single page. Thing is, I just don't have the skills...   can anybody help? I imagine this is an easy one... hopefully.

Thanks,
Brin

Comment: How exactly are you trying to call the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Call the method in the class in your template file

`WPRandomPosts::GetWPRandomPosts($cat_ID, $col, $UseExcerpt, $beforetitle, $aftertitle, $beforecite, $aftercite);`

Give the params in the function for ypur custom output.

- $col is Number of entries
- $UseExcerpt is for Display a quote
- $beforetitle is the Tag before heading out on
- $aftertitle is the Tag after the header record
- $beforecite is the Tag to quote on
- $aftercite is the Tag after a quotation on

like:

`WPRandomPosts::GetWPRandomPosts( '', 5, TRUE, '<h3>', '<h3>', '<p>', '</p>' );`

Comment: Wow...thank you very very much - easy to understand and very helpful! Worked a dream! !  !

Comment: Welcome. Please mark the answer als resolved; is usefull for other readers.